# Sometimes when I refresh my page my button's style doesn't reset

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's how the button looks like in default:

```
<button class="btn primary bidbutton">Bid Now!</button>
```

And in Javascript, during a certain event, I do the following:

```
$(this).siblings('.bidbutton').addClass("disabled");
$(this).siblings('.bidbutton').attr("disabled", "");
```

So basically this is supposed to disable the button from being clicked in a given event.

---

When I refresh the page, sometimes this dynamically assigned style is **still** applied.

Why?

Should it display it's default, manually set, style on the page?

Comment: Can you exclude, that the event is called on page initialization / refresh? - BTW: Clearing the attribute _disabled_ is not the right thing to do, if you wanted to remove the class from the element.

Comment: @Smamatti: This event is fired only once when a certain trigger I wrote happens. It's supposed to fired at the **end** of the "cycle of steps a user makes" to disable a button. I'm not supposed to renable the button at any point in time. The event isn't fired on page load, but somewhere along the line when the page is fully loaded and the user is using the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with code similar to yours on FireFox v7.0.1.  IE7 doesn't do it.  [Caching](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/) sometimes gets in the way of what you think should happen on a refresh.  On some OS's/browsers you can do a [CTRL + F5] refresh or hit [Enter] key in the address bar to force a reload (yes, it corrects the issue in FireFox).

There's an `autocomplete` attribute which can disable caching, but it doesn't help in this case.  You are at the mercy of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

How frequent does this happen?  What events are consistent every time that the style is still applied?  Things like this are not just random - there has to be some reason for it.  I'd advise adding a `console.log("DISABLED")` right before that code, and continue testing.  If the button is disabled on load WITHOUT the console message, you know something strange is going on.  If the button is disabled WITH the message, it means your code is being executed in an order that you didn't expect.  Let us know what happens!